# "[ts] Cannot find module 'react'" in spite of "npm install"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I try to update my webpack+js+react-HelloWorld webapp (which worked fine) to use Typescript instead by following [webpack's intro](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) but my editor cann't find the react module (which is defined in package.json and i ran "npm install").
So the bundle.js-file is loaded, shouldn't typescript be compiled into that one?

*src/index.tsx:*

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => (<div>Hello React with Typescript</div>);

function createAppParent() {
  let element = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  return element;
}

render((
    <App />
), createAppParent());
```

*package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "hello_world_ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "minimal configuration of webpack react and sass using typescript",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json:*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es2017",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "dist"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

*webpack.common.json:*

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'ts-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Hello React+Typescript',
        })
    ]
};
```

*webpack.dev.json:*

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ]
});
```

*webpack.prod.json:*

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ]
});
```

So what is missing?

**UPDATE:**
I use Visual Studio Code which displayed the message "[ts] Cannot find module 'react'", but it wasn't only the editor. After '*npm start*' starting the devServer i got something like "react module not found" in the firefox console.

So why is everything working now, a day later? (rhetoric question) No errors in the compiler and the dev server output works fine. I know that a reload can sometimes help an IDE but also npm?? Strange stuff, but not problem left to solve.

Comment: what editor are you using, what do you mean that the editor can't find react?  What command did you run? what was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem disappeared for unknown reasons on computer restart. (This answer is to mark question as answered.)

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding

```
"target": "ES6"
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"baseUrl": "src",
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
```

to compilerOptions